# What is the effect of polar protic solvent on nucleophilicty?

Tags: halides, nucleophilic-substitution

**Question**

[image: **enter image description here**]

**Attempt:**

I could figure out the answer correctly using simple rules governing nucleophilicity . But my doubt is how does polar protic solvent affect nucleophicity. And what would be the answer in case of polar aprotic solvent?. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protic solvents affect nucleophilicity because they form a shell around the nucleophile via their hydrogen which has a positive partial charge and therefore interacts with it, **thus the nucleophilicity will decrease**. This effect is stronger for smaller nucleophiles as they can be "trapped" more easily. So taking the classical nucleophiles you obtain this order:

$$\ce{I^-} > \ce{Br^-} > \ce{Cl^-} > \ce{F^-}$$

Aprotic solvents affect nucleophilicity in a more complex way. You can sometimes read that the previous order of nucleophile strength is inversed and small nucleophiles are favored:

$$\ce{F^-} > \ce{Cl^-} > \ce{Br^-} > \ce{I^-}$$

But be careful, this is not always true. There is more consideration to take.

- A "soft" anion is highly polarizable and has more electron density to give, making it a good nucleophile compared to "hard" ones which are tightly holding their electrons.
- This order is not respected by some polar aprotic solvents, acetone is the only one coming in my mind.